# How to run expo project on an iPhone that I connect via USB-C?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I am working on macos. And I'm trying to run my project on an iPhone that I connect via USB-C. Is there any way to do this? I'm adding my project versions. I will be grateful if you could help me.
"expo": "~48.0.21","react-native": "0.71.14","expo-cli": "^6.0.0", "@expo/cli": "^0.4.10"

Answer (score 1):

This is really quite simple - just plug the phone via a Lightning to USB cable into the Mac to get a network connection.

The network connection will be between the iPhone and the Mac only. It is not by default an internet connection for the phone, but that is not needed for Expo development.

On the Mac in System Preferences > Network, you'll see the phone listed as "iPhone USB". Click on "iPhone USB" and you'll see the phone's IP-address.

If you have other means of connection enabled on the phone, you might need to remove the checkmark from "Disable unless needed" and click Apply - but apart from that, you automatically have a network connection to the Mac now.

If you're running a macOS version where you do not see it in the graphical interface, you can instead run this Terminal command:

```
ifconfig
```

Compare the output before and after plugging in the iPhone, and you'll see that a new network interface named "enXX" (where X's are numbers) appears after plugging in the iPhone. The IP address listed is the IP address of your computer in this private network.

Now to make sure that the Expo server uses this private network instead of your WiFi for communicating with the phone, you set its initial interface like this in the Terminal:

```
export EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=169.254.246.125
export REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=169.254.246.125
expo start
```

Replace 169.254.246.125 with the actual IP address you see listed for your computer.

If you also want to share the internet connection of your Mac with the phone, you can do that from System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing. This enables NAT, so you will experience that the interface on your Mac, as well as the interface on your iPhone, now have different IP addresses, and you'll need to update the commands above accordingly.